# Bound for likelihood ratio / desity ratio of the mean of large samples

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Let ${x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,...}$ be a be a sequence of mutually independent random variables.

$x_i=1$ with probability $p_i$ and $x_i=0$ with probability $1-p_i$.

$y_i=1$ with probability $q_i$ and $y_i=0$ with probability $1-q_i$.

Assume that there exists $m>0$ such that $\frac{1}{m}<\frac{p_i}{q_i}<m$ for all $i$.

Let $\bar{x}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^{n}x_i$ and $\bar{y}_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^{n}y_i$.

How to approximate $\frac{P(\bar{x}_n=k)}{P(\bar{y}_n=k)}$ when $n$ is large for a given $k\in(0,1)$ if we know $E(\bar{x}_n)$ and $E(\bar{y}_n)$?

Thanks

Any related questions/topics/theorems are also welcome.

Comment: One related result that comes to mind is Markov's Inequality: If a random variable $Z$ is greater than $0$, and $a > 0$, then $P(Z \geq a) \leq E(Z)/a$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality

Comment: Thank you very much. That is the main problem here. There are many methods to provide bounds for cdf but no method (as far as I know) to provide bound for density and likelihood ratio